# woocommerce android app

Tags: android, android-studio, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de probar esta app de woocommerce para android:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-android

Pero no logro hacerlo funcionar en Android Studio, basicamente me dice que primero debo generar el archivo `gradle.properties`

En las instrucciones me dice que debo hacer esto:
`$ cp ./gradle.properties-example ./gradle.properties`

Justamente ahi esta  mi problema no entiendo donde se hace eso, en el terminal del propio Android Studio o dónde?

Si alguien me pude orientar o proporcionarme información, estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas puedes hacerlo desde el mismo explorador de archivos. El comando lo que esta realizando es copiar el gradle.properties-example y sustituirlo por el que ya tienes.

[image: Imagen donde puede estar situado el proyecto]

Normalmente esta situado en User > TU USUARIO > AndroidStudioProyects > TU NOMBRE DE PROYECTO

Luego debes de sustituir el gradle.properties por el que te da WooCommerce (No lo borres, guárdalo o cámbiale el nombre a -copia)

Saludos y espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado.